# Configuring Math.random() in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, uuid

I am really sorry but I am making no headway with this.  Working in expo on a basic react native shopping list and I need UUIDs for items.  I'm using Math.random ()

```
const ID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
```

and here is my list of items requiring IDs

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
        { id: ID, text: "Milk" },
        { id: ID, text: "Eggs" },
        { id: ID, text: "Butter" },
        { id: ID, text: "Veggies" },
    ]);
```

I've tried every syntatic combination I can think of for `const ID`, so each error is not the same.  I assume each time `const ID` is called the function should run and a different number should be returned.

Sorry to bother all but any help would be appreciated.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather have function `ID` so that it generate different number each time.

```
const ID = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
```

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
        { id: ID(), text: "Milk" },
        { id: ID(), text: "Eggs" },
        { id: ID(), text: "Butter" },
        { id: ID(), text: "Veggies" },
    ]);
```

Comment: I've tried that configuration and here is what I receive 'code' Component Exception ID is not a function (In 'ID()', 'ID' is 29)'code'

Comment: where did you define `ID` function. can you share more component code

Comment: `export default function App() {
 const ID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

 const [items, setItems] = useState([
  { id: ID, text: "Milk" },
  { id: ID, text: "Eggs" },
  { id: ID, text: "Butter" },
  { id: ID, text: "Veggies" },
 ]);

 const deleteItem = (id) => {
  setItems((prevItems) => {
   return prevItems.filter((item) => item.id != id);
  });
 };
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <Header />
   <FlatList
    data={items}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
     <ListItem item={item} deleteItem={deleteItem} />
    )}
   />`

Comment: I knew it. define `ID` function outside of `App` function.. put before App

Comment: I'm getting the key..it returns the same key.

Comment: thats the different issue. you have every chance of getting duplicate id as it ranges between 1 and 100 or increase it to bigger number 10000. Would advise to use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package

Comment: expo doesn't work with uuid package but I've found a polyfill for it.  THANK YOU!!!